# When extracting an RPM on MacOs using a bash script, how come I can't see the files?

Tags: bash, macos, rpm, rpmbuild

I have the following executable bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function testRpm(){
    local rpm=$1
    local tempDir=$(mktemp -d)
    pushd $tempDir #>/dev/null
    rpm2cpio $rpm | cpio -idmuv
    find store -name "*.jar"
}
testRpm $1
```

It seems pretty straight forward to me, extract the RPM, show the files.  The problem is when I run it, the find doesn't show the files, it shows the directories though.  If I manually enter the commands it works great.

eg.

```
bash -x ./test.sh myrpm.rpm
 + testRpm myrpm.rpm
 + local rpm=myrpm.rpm
++ mktemp -d
 + local tempDir=/var/folders/z4/7cl6z4_x5vq1dllx8l6vf73r0000gn/T/tmp.YWdEnKUG
 + pushd /var/folders/z4/7cl6z4_x5vq1dllx8l6vf73r0000gn/T/tmp.YWdEnKUG
 /var/folders/z4/7cl6z4_x5vq1dllx8l6vf73r0000gn/T/tmp.YWdEnKUG
   ~/IdeaProjects
 + rpm2cpio myrpm.rpm
 + cpio -idmuv 
./store/tmp/myfile1 
./store/tmp/myfile2 
33279 blocks
 + find store 
store
store/tmp
```

The above script appears to work perfectly on Redhat, but not macos.  If anyone has any suggestions, tips or solutions, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: BTW, `pushd` is an interactive extension that noninteractive shells aren't guaranteed to have. Consider just `(cd /path/to/somewhere && ...whatever...)`, so when the subshell created by the parenthesis ends, you're dumped out in the parent automatically without needing to remember to do a `popd`. If you want to avoid the performance hit of that subshell, just make the last executable in it be invoked with `exec`, thus consuming the subshell to start the process (instead of having the act of starting the process make a new subshell to consume with `execve()`, as is default behavior).

Comment: Could I ask you to post a specific RPM with which this can be tested? Right now, nobody but you has `myrpm.rpm`, so we can't inspect it to see what's going on.

Comment: I wouldn't be hugely surprised if `store/tmp` were a symlink.

Comment: I know the pushd works and the extraction works as I can inspect the directory and the contents are present.


how about 
https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/Packages/2/2ping-4.5-3.fc34.src.rpm

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying pushd doesn't work _now_, but I'm saying it may break in the future if your distro changes shells; so it's better to stop using it regardless.

Comment: BTW, re: `function funcname() {`, take out the `function` keyword -- it's a kshism that's incompatible with POSIX sh (and that bash handles in a way incompatible with legacy ksh). See the relevant entries in the 1st and 3rd tables in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: ...as for the immediate issue, I still suggest that `store/tmp` is a symlink. It's normal for `find` not to follow them.

Comment: It's not a symlink
I've tried it with no function at all.
I've tried cd

no joy yet.

[/var/folders/z4/7cl6z4_x5vq1dllx8l6vf73r0000gn/T/tmp.ZI79CpWU]$ ls -arlt

total 0

drwx------    3 cal.taylor@ibm.com  staff    96 16 Mar 15:21 .

drwxr-xr-x    3 cal.taylor@ibm.com  staff    96 16 Mar 15:21 store

drwx------@ 155 cal.taylor@ibm.com  staff  4960 16 Mar 15:26 ..

Comment: I never told you changing to cd would solve this problem. I told you only that it could prevent other problems in the future.

Comment: That said, your `ls` above is proving that `store` is not a symlink, but unless I'm misreading it (easy to believe given how poorly suited comments are for multi-line output) it says nothing about `store/tmp`.

Comment: I've tested the script on redhat today and it seems to work great there, I should have mentioned in the question that I was on macos sooner.   I'd like to thank everyone for their efforts and apologize if I've wasted your time.

Answer (score -1):

What may be happening is that when you `pushd`, you're losing access to the RPM file, e.g. when you're in `/home/me`, "foo.rpm" refers to `/home/me/foo.rpm` but when you change directory to `/tmp`, "foo.rpm" now refers to `/tmp/foo.rpm`.

Solve this by using the absolute path to the RPM when extracting using `realpath`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function testRpm(){
    local rpm=$(realpath -- "$1")
    local tempDir=$(mktemp -d)
    pushd $tempDir #>/dev/null
    rpm2cpio "$rpm" | cpio -idmuv
    find store -name "*.jar"
}
testRpm "$1"
```

Comment: thank you, but that didn't resolve the issue, same results.  I also swapped out the pushd for a cd, with no improvement.  I added a sleep as well just incase it was a weird timing issue.

Comment: after the $rpm is extracted, I couldn't care less about it tbh, I keep it only for echoing back to user.

Comment: If this were the problem, how would `cpio` be echoing the filenames?

Comment: I just tested, and this *is* an issue in the original script, and this *does* fix that issue, so I'm not sure why the downvote. My guess is the problem lies in `rpm2cpio` - maybe it's wrapped or using a fake RPM if it can't find the one specified.

Comment: You're right that this is _a_ problem in the original script, but it's inconsistent with the OP's logs, so it can't be _the_ problem that their question is about. If the OP is showing something that can't be reproduced, that question should be closed, not answered.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more specific.  I do appreciate the realpath suggestion, i've made a note of it in my bash 101 file.